# How to specify /EHa on visual studio 2003

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2003

How to specify the /EHa on visual studio .NET 2003?
Under C++ -> Code Generation, I only see the option for /EHsc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer finally at Microsoft [KB 311065](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311065): Specify 'NO' at the options and specify `/EHa` on the additional compiler command box